# PHP Session not being recognized on a particular script

Tags: php

userid SESSION is created, but on this particular script, I get "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\Workspace....process-request.php on line 6" errors. Any ideas?

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo $_GET['id'] . ": ";
}
if(isset($_GET['accepted'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['userid'];
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("druvla_public") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO requests (RequestSentByID, RequestRecipientID, StatusType, AddedMessage, FriendType)
            VALUES(1, '$id', 'Accepted', 'Welcome to Druvla', 'full')")or die(mysql_error());
    }
if(isset($_GET['denied'])) {
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

Comment: try adding session_start(); on top. also is this script in another directory, compared to the directories that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Michael, welcome to stackoverflow. do you see that checkmark at the side of the answer? click on it to accept this one as a valid answer. also go back to your other questions and accept the answers that solved your problem. this is part of stackoverflow etiquette.